# Which word can be used for a singer whose songs are mostly related to sex?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for a word, more specifically an adjective, that can describe a singer who usually uses lyrics related to sex  or some full of sexual innuendo.

So, which adjective fits best in the blanks?

> He is the second ______ singer in the world.
>
> She is the most _____/ ____ est singer in the world.

Comment: There is the term "torch singer", but it refers more to singers of songs about unrequited love.

Comment: sexually-laden  lyrics is how I would say it.

Comment: Not sure there is such a word… it would describe about 99% of mainstream singers.

Comment: Though e.g. Prince more than others, surely?

Answer (score 1):

***Raunchy*** - Energetically earthy and unrefined; sexually explicit or provocative; lewd, bawdy, suggestive (OED)

*She is the **raunchiest** singer in the world.*

Answer (score 0):

> #### Sexualised
>
> Past participle of **sexualise**:
>
> 1. to give or acquire sexual associations
> 2. To make sexual in character or quality:
>      *"[In work songs] working techniques are sexualised, and the tools and gestures of trade are turned into erotic metaphors"*   (A.L. Lloyd).

([The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sexualised))

**Sexualised** fits well into your example sentence:

> She is the most **sexualised** singer in the world.

However, there is some possible ambiguity regarding whether the *singer* is sexualised as a person or their songs are sexualised.
If you want this to be above any possible doubt, I would recommend saying something along the lines of:

> *Her songs* are the second most sexualised in the world.